# What does the at symbol (@) with IPs mean in ffmpeg and vlc?

Tags: ffmpeg, ip, vlc-media-player, mplayer

In vlc, ffmpeg, and mplayer, I see some docs and forum posts that start an IP with an at symbol, e.g., udp://@239.192.1.31:1234. Other times, I see it used to replace localhost, e.g. rtp://@:8005. What does the at symbol mean in these contexts? Searching for this answer has been difficult.

Answer (score 2):

At least in VLC (and I assume ffmpeg is the same) the @ is used to separate multicast groups from the interface section of an address.  So the following address would instruct VLC to to join the multicast group `239.255.1.2` on interface `192.168.1.10` to listen for the UDP stream:

```
udp://192.168.1.10@239.255.1.2:5004
```

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151230064625/http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch03.html#idp5151296).

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: You are incorrect.  In the example, 192.168.1.10 would tell VLC to only join the group 239.255.1.2 if it comes from a host with the source IP as 192.168.1.10. If you want to change the local interface VLC is listening on, then you might have to change your route table.  That worked for me on Win 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is for source specific multicast address. I tried it changing to my interface address and other time to transmitter address which sent media to multicast address. Second one worked.

Comment: Yeah, this for setting *IGMPv3* source ip in the next maner: `udp://SourceAddress@MulticastGroup:PortNumber`. Found here: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=70215#p293636.