# What dost the "at" (@) symbol + port numbers in VLC stream URI means?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

[I found a question about this but not fully explain my question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/870831/what-does-the-at-symbol-with-ips-mean-in-ffmpeg-and-vlc) (and its link to reference has dead...) so I opened this question.

I need to stream video + audio in MPEG-TS container, via UDP (Just ignore RTSP currently anyway).

Now assume that there are two computer **A**(`192.168.1.1`)  & **B**(`192.168.1.2`). According to days of experiments, I know I can use:

> **A**: `ffmpeg -re -i ./bunny.mp4 -codec copy -tune zerolatency -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.2:9999`
>
> **B**: `vlc -v udp://@:9999`

This indeed works very well. However, I just cannot understand what the `@` mean. I cannot duckduckgo/google such a damned symbol; though there's a sample containing in VLC's UI, BUT without any description or explanation about it: [image]

And after more experiments, I found `vlc -v udp://@:9999` in **B** is NOT equivalent to:

- `vlc -v udp://:9999`
- `vlc -v udp://127.0.0.1:9999`
- `vlc -v udp://127.0.0.1@:9999`

Above 3 ways do not work at all. So what on Earth is "@"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` stands for "myself" - any UDP adress. In your case, `vlc -v udp://@192.168.1.2:9999` would work as well. The nice thing about using the `@` shortcut is, that you don't need to hard-code your IP address into any scripts etc.

The`@` shortcut comes not from the "strict" IT side of things, but from the broadcast world, where of course networking is used quite a lot but much less understood than in the IT world proper.

**EDIT**

Let me elaborate a bit further about the use of thi shortcut:

- `224.225.226.227@:9999` would mean "the multicast IP 224.225.226.227 at any interface, where I can receive it on port 9999"
- `@192.168.169.170:9999` would mean "**my** IP 192.168.169.170, Port 9999"
- `224.225.226.227@192.168.169.170:9999` would mean "the multicast IP 224.225.226.227 at the interface where **my** IP is 192.168.169.170 on port 9999"
- `@:9999` of course would mean "any of **my** IPs on port 9999"

The important part is, that the `@` symbol makes it clear, we are talking about the own interfaces, not the sender's.

Comment: Is there any VLC official document about this? Or "@" is a whatever standard I don't know? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have seen it in a lot of broadcast equpiment - don't know in whih direction this was lifted.

Answer (score 1):

VLC now has documentation on this topic [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#Receiving_a_network_stream).

The full syntax is:
`vlc -v udp://source_address@dest_address:port`
(you can replace udp with rtp)

If **dest_address** is a multicast address then:
`source_address` is the specific source host address for the multicast group you want to join. If your local machine has IGMPv3, then a source specific multicast (SSM) join will be issued.  If the host is running a lower IGMP then the group will be joined but VLC will refuse to play the stream if it is from a different source address.
`dest_address` is the multicast group you want to join. If you have more than one network interface (including virtual interfaces), the OS's interface metrics will be used to determine which interface to listen on.
`port` is the port of the multicast group you want to listen on.

If **dest_address** is a unicast address then:
`source_address` is the specific source host address for the stream you want to play.
`dest_address` is the address of your local interface to listen on. This is useful if you have 2 or more unicast streams coming into your local machine on differing destination IP addresses but with the same destination port number. This is the only way for vlc to know which you want to play.
`port` is the port of the stream you want to play.

If you omit any or all of the 3 parameters then:
`source_address` defaults to "any address".
`dest_address` defaults to the local machine network interface address. If you have more than one interface it will find the stream based on the port number unless multiple streams are using the same port.
`port` defaults to 1234.

In your example `vlc -v udp://@:9999` computer B can play the stream from computer A because A is unicasting toward B. Omitting the source address means vlc will accept any source and omitting the destination defaults to your local interface (not the same as the loopback 127.0.0.1).

NOTE: I tested all the above scenarios on VLC 3.0.17.4 on Win10.